# modify http response (not header) in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

i want to make one website(lets say blocked.com) that is not accessible from my country to be accessible for my clients throue the custom url like notblocked.com using haproxy.

i have my haproxy box configured on the vps outside of the country. the main problem is,that website sending url redirection on the response body using javascript function and my clients getting redirected to the original web address.

how can i intersept the response body and change the domain name in the java scrip to my domain (notblocked.com) .
haproxy configuration

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  maxconn 4000
  maxsslconn 256
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  daemon
  uid 99
  gid 99

defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  timeout server 5s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 5s
  stats enable
  stats refresh 10s
  stats uri /stats

frontend https_frontend
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/kstore.pem
  no option http-server-close
  mode http
  default_backend web_server
  http-request set-header Host blocked.com
 backend web_server
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  server srv01 1.2.3.4:443 weight 1 maxconn 100 check ssl verify none
```

thanks

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854804/haproxy-subdirectory/43880162#43880162